# i'm trying to get next object from Json Array without using member name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get the next object in Json array without mentioning member name get the key value name using Javascript

```
var Commandjson = {
    "commands": {
        "MyObj.SubObj.Action.ActionEvent": {
            "Id": "MyObj.SubObj.Action.ActionEvent.CustomAction",
            "EnableRules": ["MyObj.SelectionCountExactlyOne"],
            "Actions": [{
                "ActionType": "3",
                "Attributes": {
                    "FunctionName": "MyObj.Command.close"
                },
                "Parameters": [{
                    "Name": "",
                    "ParameterName": "",
                    "ParameterType": "21",
                    "Value": "Selected"
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
};
```

From the above,
I'm trying to get the `Attributes` and `Parameters`

i tried like

```
Commandjson.commands[0].Actions[0].Attributes.FunctionName
```

But getting error as

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Actions' of undefined(…)
```

please help me what i missed.

Comment: `Commandjson.commands` isn't an array ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use

```
Commandjson.commands['MyObj.SubObj.Action.ActionEvent'].Actions[0].Attributes.FunctionName
```

because commands is not an array, but an object or use the keys of the object for a dynamic access.

```js
var Commandjson = {
    "commands": {
        "MyObj.SubObj.Action.ActionEvent": {
            "Id": "MyObj.SubObj.Action.ActionEvent.CustomAction",
            "EnableRules": ["MyObj.SelectionCountExactlyOne"],
            "Actions": [{
                "ActionType": "3",
                "Attributes": {
                    "FunctionName": "MyObj.Command.close"
                },
                "Parameters": [{
                    "Name": "",
                    "ParameterName": "",
                    "ParameterType": "21",
                    "Value": "Selected"
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
};

var commands = Object.keys(Commandjson.commands); // get all commands

console.log(Commandjson.commands[commands[0]].Actions[0].Attributes.FunctionName);
```

Comment: yes, it looks like that. maybe op should have a look to proper naming of properties.

Comment: @Nina, i am getting proper output. Thank you very much. But 'MyObj.SubObj.Action.ActionEvent' is a dynamic value, it can change context to other

Comment: @Nina, commands object name is dynamic -_'MyObj.SubObj.Action.ActionEvent'_. i'm trying to achieve the same dynamically

Comment: @SAA, then you need to get the commands first and access it like the edit above.

Comment: @Nina, it gives the actual output i needs. Thank you very much!